# Как обновить Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, binding

У меня высота `UserControl` привязана к высоте `Canvas`

```
Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}"
```

Когда `UserControl` удаляется из одного `Canvas1` и добавляется в `Canvas2`,
высота `UserControl` остаётся такой же, как и у `Canvas1`.

След. код тоже не помогает

```
var bindingHeight = userControl1.GetBindingExpression(HeightProperty);    
if (bindingHeight != null)
{
    bindingHeight.UpdateTarget();
    bindingHeight.UpdateSource();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK source у binding`а резолвится один раз (привязался к Canvas1) и привязка останентся к Canvas1 даже после перемещения объекта. Попробуйте пересоздать binding после перемещения.

Вы можете поставить брейкпоинт на биндинге и посмотреть ActualSource и узнать к какому именно канвасу он привязан.